# Deny specific browsers from accessing my app

Tags: html, reactjs, browser, routes

looking for some code that I could add in to my reactjs app that will present users with an error when accessing my app using Firefox.... Something like Browser Type is not supported.

```
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Test from './components/Test';
import Test1 from './components/Test1';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Navbar />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} /> <Route exact path="/home" component={Home} /> <Route exact path="/test" component={Test} /> <Route exact path="/test1" component={Test1} />
            <Route component={NoMatch} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Online I see some bits but I'm unsure where if should be added in to my app.jsx or my index.html or index.jsx......

Looking for someone that might have an example for me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Test from './components/Test';
import Test1 from './components/Test1';

class App extends Component {

  render() {
  if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") > 0) {
      return <div>Browser not supported </div>
    }
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Navbar />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} /> <Route exact path="/home" component={Home} /> <Route exact path="/test" component={Test} /> <Route exact path="/test1" component={Test1} />
            <Route component={NoMatch} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```